# initialize c_char_p to pass to C function

Tags: python, pointers, ctypes

C function has output parameter:

```
___OUT_ char* param
```

and I am trying to pass a `c_char_p` from my Python when calling c function:

```
param = (ctypes.c_char_p)()
```

but I am getting `ERROR: output parameter is NULL`. How can I fix this issue? Should I initialize param?

Comment: @eryksun: I have passed types.byref(param), still same null error.

Comment: OK, I see now. Your function takes a `char *param`, not `char **param`. So you need to pass a `c_char` array. Do you know how big the buffer should be? Is there another parameter for the size?

Comment: @eryksun there is no parameter for the size.

Comment: @eryksun, no  nothing , I only have the function information and there is no parameter for size of this argument. I have edited my question with all args.